# UrlRewritting + ASP.NET AJAX + IIS 7 on localhost + IIS 7 Remote

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-ajax, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net, scriptresource.axd

I am getting these issue in my website if i use UrlRewritting with ASP.NET AJAX

1. I was getting ScriptResource.axd 404 Error on Devserver I removed that by using Rewrite rule for that and add that following code in web.config's section

<httpHandlers>
<add verb="GET,HEAD"
path="ScriptResource.axd"
type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

that method fixed my problem... but

1. I configured on my local PC's IIS 7 It is creating same problem so found the solution for IIS 7. I removed above and and add new code in web.config's section

   <handlers>

<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

</handlers>

that code fixed my problem...... but

1. when I configure on remote IIS i am getting same problem........ any one can answer How can I solve that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution actually problem is version of System.Web.Extensions I changed version Version=1.0.61025.0 to Version=3.5.0.0 and it is work now.....